# Thymeleaf not replacing fragment with ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, thymeleaf

I am [looking from here](https://riptutorial.com/thymeleaf/example/28530/replacing-fragments-with-ajax)

This is my main html

```
<button id="retrieve-user-btn"  onclick="retrieveUserInfo()" type="button">Bilgileri getir</button>
    </div>
 <div class="row" id="user-details-div">
</div>

</th:block>


<th:block layout:fragment="script">
    <script>
        var selectedUserId;

        function retrieveUserInfo() {
            var url = '/internal-user/'+selectedUserId;
            console.log("retrieveUserInfo url " + url);
debugger
            $("#user-details-div").load(url);
        }
```

i can see the url when i click button from console:

http://localhost:8090/internal-user/3

Then it goes here

```
@GetMapping(value = "internal-user/{id}")
public String getUserById(Model model, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    model.addAttribute("user", service.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));

    return "internal-user-detail :: user-details";
}
```

But then it returns only string. When i go to that url, also i see

```
internal-user-detail :: user-details
```

All my html's are under templates. **    internal-user-detail**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div th:fragment="content1">
    This is Content 1
</div>

<div th:fragment="user-details">

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <input th:text="#{user.firstname}">firstname</input>
            <input th:text="#{user.lastname}">lastname</input>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**internal-user-detail :: user-details** this means go to

```
internal-user-detail html
```

and bring **user-details** fragment but it does not do it.

There is no error or warnings on idea or browser.

Why cant it bring?

This is also user dto

```
public class InternalUserDTO  {

private Long id;

private String firstname;



private String lastname;
```

I also tried for

```
        return "internal-user-detail :: content1";
```

but same. I will bring all user info as inputs so it will be editable. But then it needs to send after clicking edit.

In same controller, I also have another endpoind:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"internal-user/save"})
    public ModelAndView getSaveUserView() {
```

So

```
@GetMapping(value = "internal-user/{id}")
@GetMapping(value = {"internal-user/save"})
```

two of them looks same but i can follow from debug. There is no problem

Comment: By any chance, you are using `@RestController` annotation at the class level? If yes change it to `@Controller`.

Comment: @fiveelements yes but it was working with `restcontroller` in the morning but i will try now.